# ruby: `read': Invalid argument -(Errno::EINVAL) at File.read

Tags: ruby, directory, crc, crc32

I'm doing a simple script to check crc of all files...

```
require "zlib"
exit if Object.const_defined?(:Ocra)

files = Dir.glob("*")

File.open('dir.txt', 'a+') do |file|  
 file.puts files
end

File.read('dir.txt').each_line { |line|
    file = File.read(line) ; nil
    file_crc = Zlib.crc32(file,0).to_s(16)
    puts line, file_crc
}
```

The problem is at the line `File.read('dir.txt').each_line { |line|`
I get this error:

```
test.rb:13:in `read': Invalid argument - 1.exe (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/1.rb:13:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/1.rb:12:in `each_line'
        from C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/1.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

PD: `1.exe` is a file listed in the "dir.txt".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you checked that the line doesn't contain extra characters? `p line`.

IIRC `line` will contain the newline character, use `line.chomp`.

Comment: oh tahnkyou, all the lines contained a "\n" chars solved: File.read(line[0..-2])

Comment: `File.read(line.strip)` is probably the more robust variant. Esp. if you have windows line-endings of `\r\n`. Although you then can't have spaces at the beginning and end of the filename, don't know if windows even allows that.