# Ruby - STDIN.read

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read from a file, and because my more complex code doesn't work, I came back to basics to see whether it even reads properly.
My code:

```
   MyParser.new(STDIN.read).run.lines.each do |line|
     p line.chomp
   end
```

I use

```
ruby program
```

(it's placed in a `bin` directory and I saved it without `.rb` )

Now program is waiting for me to write something. I type:

```
../examples/file.txt
```

and use `CTRL + Z` (I'm on Windows 10). It produces `^Z` and I hit enter.
Now I have an error:

```
Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - ../examples/file.txt (Errno::EINVAL)
```

`MyParser` class and its whole logic works fine. I'll be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby: \`read': Invalid argument -(Errno::EINVAL) at File.read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152273/ruby-read-invalid-argument-errnoeinval-at-file-read)

Comment: I've seen this one and used line.chomp, the same error.

Comment: Did you try `MyParser.new(STDIN.read.strip).whatever`?

Comment: @Jes does `MyParser.new` expect a file name as its argument?

Comment: Have you tried using `ARGV` instead? Asking for filenames as input is *annoying*.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing, what your MyParser expect, it is hard to know, what you need.

But maybe this helps:

```
 MyParser.new(STDIN.gets.strip).run.lines.each do |line|
   p line.chomp
 end
```

I would extend it by a message what you need:

```
puts "Please enter the filename"
STDOUT.flush
MyParser.new(STDIN.gets.strip).run.lines.each do |line|
  p line.chomp
end
```

With `STDOUT.flush` the user gets the message, before `STDIN.gets`waits for a message.

---

In your case I would take a look on ARGV and call the program with:

```
ruby program ../examples/file.txt
```

Your program should then use:

```
MyParser.new(ARGV.first).run.lines.each do |line|
  p line.chomp
end
```